# Erase an element in vector, which is allocted using 'new' operator

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector, struct

please help me understand this case:

I am working in a project of storing data to a `vector` of `struct`, my goal is to keep them alive until I call a function to work with the data, then erase them in the queue. But my problem is I don't know how to safely erase the element in vector if I allocate the `struct` using `new` operator.

Example:

```
//definition of truct
struct MData {
    int dHeight;
    int dWidth;
};

//definition of queue
std::vector< MData* > dataQueue;
```

**This is how I store data in the queue:**

```
//when got the data
MData* mData = new MData; 
mData->dHeight = sourceHeight;
mData->dWidth = sourceWidth;

//Then put it in the queue
dataQueue.push_back( MData);
```

After calculating, I want to erase the first element in the queue

So what method should I use: `delete dataQueue.front()`? to free the memory. Or using `dataQueue.erase(dataQueue.front())`?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you have a type error -- your std::vector<T> has MDatas (the actual struct) but you're trying to push a pointer to MData.  That won't work.  For cleaning up a struct allocated by new, try taking it off the list first, then deleting the pointer.  (You don't _have_ to do it in two steps, but it makes it easier to see what's going on.)

Comment: dataQueue.push_back(MData);` won't compile because `MData` is a struct, not an object.`mData->dWidth = sourceWidth` won't compile because you forgot the semicolon. So I'm 100% sure that that **not** how you store data in the queue.

Comment: Sorry guys, I don't have any complier at the time posting this, I just plain texting the code above. I have edited those error.

Comment: @TrungNguyen In relation to your updated code: you should _not_ use containers of raw pointers like `std::vector<MData*>`; it's too easy to leak resources, as your question alludes to. In this case, you should preferably use `std::vector<MData>`, but in general cases where you don't want to store by value, use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<...>>`.

Comment: If you are storing pointer to MData in vector, then erase will just remove the element from the vector, but the actual object itself won't be freed.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young: There's nothing wrong with having containers of raw pointers. The problem is in using raw pointers to manage dynamically allocated objects. Whether those raw pointers are in a container or not is beside the point.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley It's true that if what you're containing is, semantically, just pointers, there's no problem. But people using it to hold dynamically allocated objects is such a common theme that when I see code where containers of raw pointers are used, alarm bells go off. And 100% agree that the real problem is using raw pointers to hold dynamically allocated objects, containers or no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would you allocate `MData` using `new`? It's small enough that you can just allocate it in automatic storage, especially since your `dataQueue` is already defined to hold `MData` instances by value (and not by pointer). Thus:

```
MData mData{sourceHeight, sourceWidth};
dataQueue.push_back(mData);
```

Comment: or `dataQueue.push_back({sourceHeight, sourceWidth});`, or `dataQueue.emplace_back(sourceHeight, sourceWidth);`

Comment: Note for the OP: in this case mData is copied into the vector not referenced or moved.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are going to use the object inside the vector and no need to live outside it, the best practice is to emplace it inside the vector directly:

```
 struct MData {
        MData(const int dHeight,const int dWidth):dHeight(dHeight),dWidth(dWidth){}
        int dHeight;
        int dWidth;
    };
    std::vector<MData> dataQueue;
    dataQueue.emplace_back(sourceHeight,sourceWidth);
```

[Online Demo](http://cpp.sh/9hhv7)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the C++ STL queue library,

```
MData* firstelement = dataQueue.front();
dataQueue.pop();
delete firstelement;
```

Edit: as pointed out by Dave, you need to define the vector as follows:

```
std::vector< MData* > dataQueue;
```

Comment: No, it's better to use `std::vector<MData>` (storing the `MData` by value) than `std::vector<MData*>` (storing the `MData` by _raw_ pointer). Containers of raw pointer are an antipattern. If you must use a container of pointers, use a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr`. But in this instance, it's not called for (it's just a struct with 2 `int`s); storing by value is better.

Comment: `MData firstelement` should be `MData *firstElement`